# Sound works in emulator but not on phone

Tags: android

I have this code

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.blah);

        Button Button01 = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        Button01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onClick(View v){}

    public void disclaimerBTN (View v){
        Toast.makeText(this, "FAILED:   The remote object is " +
                            "not responding to this command",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

When I use in my emulator, it works, but if I use my phone to test, it doesn't play the sound.

I have no reference to this code in my button.. should I?

Comment: check your device volume.

Comment: In my other button, which displays a TOAST caption, I have android:onClick="reference to code" or similar... should I have something in the button I click for the sound? to refernce the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code...

```
   MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer().create(context, R.raw.blah);
```